# how to configure Jmeter to discard downloaded files?

Tags: memory-management, jmeter

first of all i already had a look at several questions which are quite similar. But i wasn't able to find a solution.

My script performs a load test it calls several different URLs(GET http) to download the content behind.
After 120 requests the memory usage increases up to 2GB and after 500 to 5-6GB

I changed already the xmx size in hope that this will solve the problem but it doesn't.

Is there any way to configure jmeter to not save the files coming from a response? Or lets say to discard immediately the downloaded files?
Is it maybe an JRE setting?

Or is there no way to solve this memory increasing problem?

Br,
Kabba

Comment: sry forgotten: I have disabled all listener and started jmeter in command line mode to decrease the memory usage but unfortunately the impact was marginal.

Comment: without any enabled listeners, there isn't much that can consume memory like this. give more details of your test plan and check jmeter.log for errors.

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling the `View Results Tree` in the script as it records all results for you to inspect.

The jMeter documentation specifically mentions this:

> 18.3.6 View Results Tree
>
> View Results Tree MUST NOT BE USED during load test as it consumes a
>   lot of resources (memory and CPU). Use it only for either functional
>   testing or during Test Plan debugging and Validation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is something you can do via JMeter settings. As per [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide (make sure that you follow all the recommendations):

> Default JMeter java configuration comes with 512 Mo and very little GC tuning.
>   First ensure you set -Xmx option value to a reasonable value regarding your test requirements.
>   Then change MaxNewSize option in jmeter file to respect the original ratio between MaxNewSize and -Xmx.
>   Finally try tuning GC options only if you master this domain.

So you can try different Garbage Collection options on JMeter's side. See [How to Tune Java Garbage Collection](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-tune-java-garbage-collection/) guide for ramp-up on the domain or consult a Java developer if one is around.