# JMeter Clear JDBC response data

Tags: java, memory, jmeter, performance-testing, ram

We are running a test at this moment stressing a database using JMeter. We are sending a bunch of queries and the database responds with the result set of each query.

When the data returns, it stays in the memory RAM of the machine we are using to execte the JMeter test. We do not want that as it fills up the memory, slows the test and pretty soon we get an out-of-memory error from the JVM. What is the best way to handle that?

Is there a way to save the data in a csv file somewhere or to clear the memory RAM?  We don't really care about the data that returns. All we care is to measure the performance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to configure Jmeter to discard downloaded files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464526/how-to-configure-jmeter-to-discard-downloaded-files)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share an overview over your JMeter run configuration, to get an idea where the results might be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, the only way I can think of is calling [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) statements via [execute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) function instead of [executeQuery()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)), this way you will not get the [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) which means that the memory consumption of JMeter will be less.

It can be achieved in 2 ways

1. Patch [AbstractJDBCTestElement](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/src/protocol/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jdbc/AbstractJDBCTestElement.java) class
2. Switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and code your database load testing logic fully in Groovy, something like the approach described in the [Cassandra Load Testing with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cassandra-load-testing-with-groovy) article.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter will automatically free up memory from resources which are no longer required. So it looks like your run configuration requires a reference to the received results.

If you are using a `View Results Tree`, you should remove it from your run configuration.

[As stated in the documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree):

> View Results Tree MUST NOT BE USED during load test as it consumes a lot of resources (memory and CPU). Use it only for either functional testing or during Test Plan debugging and Validation.